# Shared attribute in pydantic BaseModel

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have the following pydantic models

```py
class Bar(BaseModel):
    foo: int
    
class Foo(BaseModel):
   bar: int
   ba: Bar
```

Is there a way to access the `bar` attribute from the `Foo` model when running a validation on the `foo` attribute of the `Bar` model? I want to do something like this

```py
 class Bar(BaseModel):
    foo: int
    
    @validator('foo')
    def validate_foo(cls, value, values):
        
        if cls.bar > 1: 
            return 1 
     
        return 0
```

I've tried accessing the `cls.__fields__` attribute but i've found nothing there, is there a better way to do this? Any advice is more than welcome.

Comment: Bar is independent of Foo, so it doesn't know anything about it. You could have a validator in Foo for ba that access bar though.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify what your intentions are by doing that validation.